# Is it possible to overflow column labels in wxpython grid?

Tags: grid, wxpython, overflow

I'd like to know if it is possible to overflow column labels in wxpython grid. I can overflow cells over multiple columns following way:

```
self.SetCellSize(0, 0, 3, 1)
```

But how to overflow column labels?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that this is currently supported. There was a "sort of" recent addition called the gridlabelrenderer that allows the developer to add colors and font styles to the columns and rows. See the wxPython demo for an example. It uses a wx.DC to do the custom drawing. To me, I would think you could take that code an extend it (i.e. subclass) to make it draw where you wanted...although I don't know how that would affect column size changes.